# Display Templates: how to get url link from current item?

Tags: display-template

I am building a display template. I would like to know which column of the current item is the url to the item? I see alot of columns which I can select in the mapping columns section of the search content webpart.

Is it this one?

```
'Link URL'{Link URL}:'Path'
```

Comment: Path should be the one, yes

Answer (score 4):

The managed property 'Path' contains the link to the item. Make sure you encode it properly.

> var encodedPath = $urlHtmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Path);